# Is it possible to setContentInset of ABPeoplePicker & UIImagePickerController?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, abpeoplepickerview

I know it's possible to add a inset for a UITableView like so:

```
[self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 46, 0)];
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 46, 0)];
```

Is it possible for a ABPeoplePicker & UIImagePickerController (sourceTypePhotoLibrary)?

Thanks!

Coulton

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the Table view of ABPeoplePicker and then probably try applying your changes there

```
     for (UITableView *tbl in picker.topViewController.view.subviews)
     {
         //Your changes here
       [tbl setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 46, 0)];
       [tbl setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 46, 0)];

     }
```

I have no clue regarding UIImagePickerController so can't help you with that

Hope this helps